# How to minify and copy modified files with Gulp?

Tags: gulp

I have JS files in `/app/js` and want to minify and copy them to `/dist/js/min` when modified. I currently have this in my `gulpfile`:

```
gulp.task('minifyJs', function () {
    gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
                         suffix: '.min'
                     }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/js/min'))
    ;
});
```

And this in the default task:

```
gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', ['lint', 'minifyJs']);
```

The problem here is that whenever a single JS file is modified, **all** JS files in the directory get minified and copied, which really slows things down.

How do I make it so that only the modified file gets minified and copied? For example, is there a way to pass the name of the modified file to the task and use it as the `src()` parameter in the task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gulp-changed](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed) so that only the file that was changed gets processed.

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('minifyJs', function () {
  gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
    .pipe(changed('/dist/js/min'))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
                  suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/js/min'));
});
```